# Conditions Proper Frame

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, coordinate-systems

Suppose that we have an arbitrary trajectory in Minkowski space given by
$$ t = p(\tau) \quad \text{and} \quad z = q(\tau)\,. $$
I would like to find a transformation that brings me to the proper (comoving) frame, where the trajectory is at rest. However, I have absolutely no idea how to start on this problem. I tried the following general transformation:
$$ t = f\left(t',z'\right) \quad \text{and} \quad z = g\left(t',z'\right)\,,$$
and tried to derive a differential equation from it, but this didn't do the trick.